# How to determine if input is a ratio or float in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, floating-point, scanf, fractions

I need to batch-process text files of **mixed units,** i.e. integer ratios and floating-point numbers (which are scaled logarithmic approximations of unknown rational or irrational numbers). How can Matlab detect which input is which? Would scanning for a '.' or '/' character be best?

252.63

4/3

757.89

2/1

In this example I recognize that the numbers represent values in increasing order (but in mixed units, which is typical in my field of study), and I would process 252.63 and 757.89 differently from 4/3 and 2/1.

I haven't found a function in Matlab like `isa(x, 'rat')` where *x* is any one of the lines in the above list, and 'rat' would be ratio.

Comment: If the input is text, I would simply scan for `/` on each line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab can search strings for specific characters pretty trivially.

```
slashmask     = str == '/'; % returns false for every character in str that's not a slash, and true for every one that is.
slashdetected = any(slashmask); % returns false if no character is a slash.
```

if all you need to do is take the ratio and evaluate it and then use it in the same way as the floats, you could just simply use the "eval" function to retrieve the float equivalent.

Comment: Much better to use `str2double` than `eval`. `eval` is dangerous becuase it can run arbitrary code, it slows down the code, and is considered bad practice, so [it should be avoided](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html). Other than that, good answer!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your tips. With your help I settled on this (per line of data file):

```
x = fgetl(fileId);
if isnan(str2double(x)) == true
    % Interpret string as ratio number
    x = str2num(x);
    % then convert to musical cents,
    s(i) = log(x) / log(2) * 1200;
else
    % convert string to float, already in cents.
    s(i) = str2double(x);
end
```

Comment: You should save `str2double(x)` in a variable, it is evaluated twice for no reason. Like, `y= str2double(x); if isnan(y) ... else s(i)=y; end`

Comment: Also, comparing `a==true`, with `a` a logical value, is pointless. `if isnan(...)` is the same and easier to read (IMO). -- And note that `str2num` calls `eval` internally, with all the associated dangers. If there is a chance that a malicious attacker modifies the input file, you need to consider validating the input first (i.e. make sure it contains only digits and `/`, which is easy to do with `all(isstrprop(x,'digit')|(x=='/'))`). In some situations, worrying about this is totally pointless, in others it is not. But it is good to know about it!